# STDIN.o# and STDIN.e# files not found on cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, job-scheduling, qsub, torque

I am currently using a cluster that is using TORQUE. Recently when I submit jobs with qsub their status can be checked with qstat but no STDIN.e12345678 or STDIN.o12345678 files can be found (numbers of jobs just examples). Using the qstat -f command showed that the files should be located in my home directory, but they are not there (also not hidden). What could be the problem?

I hope I address the problem to the right Q+A page. In addition I am merely a user without much understanding what the cluster is doing, so please excuse if I use a wrong expression.

Comment: What directory were you in when you submitted the job? They could be in there. If you use Moab or Maui run 'checkjob -v -v 42'. There could be an error scping the files.

Comment: @spuder: It's weird - next morning and the thing works again. I used the exact same command from the terminal history! The thing is, that the documentation of the cluster is not really helpful if you are a beginner. So how can I check if I use Moab / Maui? Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you use Moab or maui, you will be able to run `checkjob` or `shwoq`. your sys admin should know.